# How to convert contacts under an organisation to person accounts

Tags: data-loader, contact, person-accounts

I am currently working for an organisation which has put a bunch of clients under an organisation called 'individual', I am currently trying to convert these contacts to person accounts but unsure as to which way to go about it.

I have done a bit of research and haven't found anything that is linked to what I'm trying to do, so I have thought that maybe I could One of the ways which I thought this could be done would be through firstly converting those contacts using data loader into business accounts and then from there converting them into person accounts- but it just seems a bit of a long winded way to go about it. I am also unsure as to what fields I will need when mapping on data loader to make this transition smooth.

If anyone has any suggestions please do comment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple process that takes just a few steps. First, query `SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Account.Name = 'Individual'`. Next, using that csv, insert new accounts, mapping Name to Name, and leaving Id unmapped. After that, take the success####.csv file, update contacts, mapping the Account Id (001) column to AccountId, and mapping the Contact Id (003) to Id. Using either success file, add a column with the record type Id, the value should be the Person Account Record Type Id that you want to use. After updating the CSV, go to update accounts, mapping the Account Id to Id and the Record Type Id column to RecordTypeId.

You could even conceptually do this in apex code:

```
RecordType personRt = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE IsPersonType = TRUE limit 1];
Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Account.Name = 'Individual'];
Account[] accounts = new Account[0];
for(Contact record: contacts) {
  accounts.add(new Account(Name=record.Name));
}
insert accounts;
for(Integer index = 0; index < accounts.size(); index++) {
  contacts[index].AccountId = accounts[index].Id;
}
update contacts;
for(Account record: accounts) {
  record.RecordTypeId = personRT.Id;
}
update accounts;
```

Add a LIMIT clause to the contact query if you have too many rows. You can run this script repeatedly until there are no more records.

You could also adapt this to a batchable or queueable class.